# How to change background color of specific character in react/typescript using regex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, typescript

I have a component that has mapped data. My task is to change the background color of specific characters. In this case, they are "Miss", "Mrs", "Ms". I know I can use regex but I keep getting an error object is possibly null.

This is the component and what I have tried.

```
const h2 = document.querySelector("h2")
h2.innerHTML = h2.textContent.replace(/[ms]/g, "<span class='title'>Miss</span>");


.title {
background-color: blue;
}

.map((d: any) => (
              
          <div style={hoverStyle} className=" ease-in-out delay-150 hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-110 duration-300  border-white shadow-slate-500 bg-white hover:bg-slate-200 rounded-lg container p-5">
            <img className="rounded-full w-44 h-44 " src={d.picture.large} />
            <h2>{d.name.title}</h2>
            <h3 className="font-bold text-3xl font-serif">
              {" "}
             {d.name.first} {d.name.last}
            </h3>
            <p className=" text-md  ">Gender: {d.gender}</p>
            
            <p className=" text-md bg-blue-300 text-white ">Contact: {d.email}</p>
            <p className=" text-md  ">
              City: {d.location.city}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

This is the code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mclean-nrhcdq?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This won't solve it, but make sure you refer to the right group in the regex replacement, i.e. replace `.replace(/[ms]/g, "<span class='title'>$1</span>")` with `.replace(/[ms]/g, "<span class='title'>$&</span>")`

Comment: .replace(/[ms]/g, "<span class='title'>Miss</span>" - would this work?

Comment: Sorry, without a codepen, it is hard to test. Certainly, the `.replace(/[ms]/g, "<span class='title'>Miss</span>")` will replace any `m` or `s` with `<span class='title'>Miss</span>`.

Comment: ill create one, thanks for your time

Comment: You shouldn't be using native DOM methods like `querySelector` with React.

Comment: Hi Andy, you could improve your comment - instead of "You shouldn't be using native DOM methods like querySelector with React" you could say You shouldn't be using native DOM methods like querySelector with React, you should be using "x". Thanks

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) @shar27.

Answer (score 0):

I belief you can still accomplish this in the map function.. You can do a check using a ternary operator such as 

### {d.name.title!==undefined &&d.name.title.includes('ms')?'Miss': d.name.title}

..  You can do this outside to make your html clean and readble. To change the background color you can also apply a class conditionally using the back tick character

Comment: Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: I tried it like this -  <h2 className={d.name.title.includes('Ms')?'Miss': 'title'}>{d.name.title}</h2> but everything got highlighted